# What happens if power (or another problema arises) during a RAID level upgrade?

Tags: raid, 3ware

I have a server with a 3ware RAID card in Raid 5 and I am currently on the process of converting to raid 6.

My question is simple: if some problem arises like a power failure, one of the disks breaks or some IO errors happen in one what will happen to the raid?

Comment: This is highly dependent on the RAID card. It would be a better question for the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

well, theoretically it is safe, because raid6 adds another parity block, so there is no data deletion. if the power goes off, conversion fails, and you go back to where you started from.

however, as all good system admins know, it is mandatory to back up your data whenever you do something that could affect the data. this is just the best practice, regardless what the raid controller might do.